# Background Color CssBaseline Material ui is not working in production (heroku)

Tags: reactjs, heroku, material-ui

I've been working with react and material ui library, and i have this App.js component wrapping the rest of my app. The theme is working properly in production and locally BUT the background color is working locally but not in production. I wonder if i am missing something that i need to consider for production.. The background color in production is just white. I've tried with different colors and it is not working.

This is my App.js code

```
import React from 'react'
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { CssBaseline } from '@material-ui/core';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        background:{
            default: 'red',
        },
        primary: {
            main: '#003520',
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#58585A',
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        typography: {
            fontSize: 8,
        },
    },
});

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <CssBaseline />
                ....
            </ThemeProvider >
        )
     }
}
```

Comment: If you inspect the page using Chrome developer tools, you should be able to find the `<style>` tag in the `<head>` containing the styles generated by `CssBaseline` (should look like `<style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiCssBaseline">`). It would be helpful to see what is in that and also to see the styles for the body element if you inspect it. My guess would be that your production app has some competing CSS that is also styling the background.

Comment: Thank you @RyanCogswell for your help, you were right. I had a conflict with another library..

Comment: Please close the question if you have found the solution.